# How would one go about printing/saving a dictionary that uses Class Instances?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, save, instance-variables

I've tried a dozen or so different ways to solve this today, but sadly no dice so far. As of right now, I'm currently attempting to save a dictionary but running into an unfortunate side effect on account of the values that the keys utilize being sourced from a Class. When I print/save this dictionary as is, I receive the following output.

> {'imperialguard': <**main**.Entity object at 0x00000180CC2E1FD0>,
> 'orkboy': <**main**.Entity object at 0x00000180CC2E1FA0>}

As one can imagine, this information is not very useful as a dictionary. What I am attempting to print/save can be gleaned below.

```
entities = {
'imperialguard': Entity('Imperial Guardsman', 10, '3/6/9/18', 'Lasgun', 'Knife'),
'orkboy': Entity('Ork Boy', 12, '3/6/9/18', 'Slugga', 'Choppa')}
```

I've attempted methods such as using print(repr(entities)), but all has seemed to come up short. I would greatly appreciate any insight, and I will post a longer code snippet below to provide more context.

```
class Entity:

    woundChange = 0

    def __init__(self, name, wounds, movement, weapon, melee):
        self.name = name
        self.wounds = wounds
        self.movement = movement
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.melee = melee

    def array(self):
        return '{}; HP: {}, {}, {}, {}'.format(self.name, self.wounds, self.movement, self.weapon, self.melee)


entities = {
    'imperialguard': Entity('Imperial Guardsman', 10, '3/6/9/18', 'Lasgun', 'Knife'),
    'orkboy': Entity('Ork Boy', 12, '3/6/9/18', 'Slugga', 'Choppa')
}

print(entities)
print(repr(entities)

z = open("entities.txt", "w")
z.write(str(entities))
z.close()
```

I wish you all the best, and thank you for reading.

Comment: use pickle maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the dictionary to a string representation.  Add a `__str__(self)` method to the class.  Then, convert the dictionary using a Dictionary comprehension and the dictionary's items() method as in:

```
class Entity:

    woundChange = 0

    def __init__(self, name, wounds, movement, weapon, melee):
        self.name = name
        self.wounds = wounds
        self.movement = movement
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.melee = melee

    def array(self):
        return '{}; HP: {}, {}, {}, {}'.format(self.name, self.wounds, self.movement, self.weapon, self.melee)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}; HP: {}, {}, {}, {}'.format(self.name, self.wounds, self.movement, self.weapon, self.melee)

str_dict = {k: str(v) for k, v in entities.items()}
```

test:

```
print(str_dict)

z = open("entities.txt", "w")
z.write(str(str_dict))
z.close()
```

results:

```
{'imperialguard': 'Imperial Guardsman; HP: 10, 3/6/9/18, Lasgun, Knife', 'orkboy': 'Ork Boy; HP: 12, 3/6/9/18, Slugga, Choppa'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods of the class.

There are some built-in functions that the class `Entity` inherits from the object class. `__str__` is a method that instructs what to display when the object is treated as a string. Similarly, `__repr__` method that instructs what to display when the object is passed to a file handler (could be stdout, stderr, or a file). Thus, to get a human friendly output, override the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods of the class.

```py
class Entity:
    # ...
    # ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.array()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.array()
```